# Teste fim do arquivo em C

Tags: c

Olá, estou com um problema e não consegui resolver.

```
while(!feof(arquivo)) {
    fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
    fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
    printf("%d",result);

    fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
    fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
    printf("%d",result);

    fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
    fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
    printf("%d",result);

    fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^\n]",&result);
    printf("%d",result);

}
```

Meu código deveria ler um arquivo de texto formatado da seguinte forma:

```
5, 1, 2, 3
4, 3, 1, 8
```

Após fazer a leitura ao invés do resultado do print ser: 51234318 ele sempre imprime 512343188888, achei que pudesse ser resolvido trocando while por "do while", mas o problema persistiu.
O que eu preciso modificar para que a leitura termine no momento esperado?

A função completa é essa:

```
void alocaProcesso(FILE *arquivo){
   char *linha;
   char *valor;
   int result;
   if(arquivo == NULL){
       printf("Problemas na leitura do arquivo");
       return;
   }
   while(!feof(arquivo)) {
      fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
      fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
      printf("%d",result);

      fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
      fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
      printf("%d",result);

      fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
      fseek(arquivo,+1,SEEK_CUR);
      printf("%d",result);

      fscanf(arquivo, "%d",&result);
      printf("%d",result);

   }
   fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a leitura ainda não bateu no fim de arquivo (EOF) quando o loop vai para o terceiro ciclo, e feof() ainda retorna FALSE. Testando EOF logo depois de tentar ler o primeiro número da linha via fscanf():

```
   while(1) {
      fscanf(arquivo, "%d[^,]",&result);
      if (feof(arquivo)) {
          break;
      }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Aqui não funcionou.